# Disable the native keyboard on Ionic

Tags: javascript, ionic-framework

Clearly solutions like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30499237/ionic-keyboard-hide-on-input-focus) do not work as expected on Android 5.1.* (the KB flickers (quickly opens & closes)).

```
.directive('disableKeyboard', function ($timeout, $window) {
    var linker = function (scope, element, attrs) {

        if (!$window.cordova || !$window.cordova.plugins.Keyboard) {
            return;
        }

        element.bind('focus click',
            function (e) {
                e.preventDefault();
                $timeout($window.cordova.plugins.Keyboard.close, 0);
            }
        );
    };

    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        link: linker,
    }
})
```

The Ionic [forum](http://forum.ionicframework.com/t/how-to-prevent-the-keyboard-appearance/12963/2) has not given meaningful solutions. Any suggestions?
Please note: I would like to avoid `cordova.plugins.Keyboard.close`. Thank you.

Comment: what is exact behavior you want? like what is the input field? how do you want to add data into that field etc? may be sharing template side will help us to give you workaround.

Comment: @mudasserajaz The expected behaviour - to disable the native keyboard on some pages (i.e. to stay closed on _focus / click_ events).

Comment: try just adding `disabled` attribute to those input elements.

Comment: @mudasserajaz Great, this works! Please post the comment as an answer.

Comment: I have added my answer :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add `disabled` attribute to your input tag, for example

```
<input type="text" name="lname" disabled>
```

NOTE: This might change background color of input tag, but you can change that using css.

Comment: This is the solution.

Answer (score 1):

I know that I'm late, but I've developed this library to do exactly that: https://www.npmjs.com/package/ionic-no-keyboard. It has no flicker and it does exactly that. It disabled the native keyboard. Just add the `no-keyboard` tag on the input and the native keyboard will be disabled.

Answer (score 1):

**Updated January 22, 2022:**

While reading the `Virtual Keyboard API` document here: https://github.com/MicrosoftEdge/MSEdgeExplainers/blob/main/VirtualKeyboardPolicy/explainer.md I noticed that it referred to an `inputmode` attribute that could be used to change what type of Virtual Keyboard layout should be shown (numeric, telephone, numeric, etc).

Within this document, they mentioned that a value of `none` could be used to hide the Virtual Keyboard, and after looking up the attribute in the MDN documents, sure enough, the `none` value is meant to be used when the page (in this case the Mobile App) implements its own keyboard: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/inputmode#values
[image]

Unlike the other solutions, this attribute will retain the focus on the `input` element and will still permit the user to perform multi-selections and context menu actions (i.e. copy/paste, select all, etc).

This attribute can be used on inputs:

```
<input inputmode="none">
```

As well as on any element that is made editable through the `contenteditable` attribute:

```
<div inputmode="none" contenteditable />
```

I tested this functionality both on the iOS (XCode) and Android (Android Studio) simulators/emulators and it worked on both!

**Original Answer January 15: 2022:**

Thankfully it looks like a new Web API is in the works called the `Virtual Keyboard API`.

I won't elaborate much on the new API itself, because I already did so in [another Stack Overflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70718382/3513260).

The new API [introduced a new attribute](https://www.w3.org/TR/virtual-keyboard/#extensions-to-the-elementcontenteditable-mixin) called `virtualKeyboardPolicy` which can be set to `auto` or `manual`.

When set to `manual` the Virtual Keyboard will **not** show up automatically when an `input` element is focused, but unlike the other solutions, the `input` **will** remain focused and permit the user to perform multi-character selections, copy/paste, etc.

The feature was [shipped in Chromium v94](https://chromestatus.com/feature/5680057076940800) (which was released on September 21, 2021), so  I did some testing in a couple of Chromium based browsers, and it seems that the new attribute already works!

```
<input
  virtualkeyboardpolicy="auto"
  value="Auto Virtual Keyboard"
>
```

[image]
[image]

Notice that the Virtual Keyboard is hidden in the following images!

```
<input
  virtualkeyboardpolicy="manual"
  value="Manual Virtual Keyboard"
>
```

[image]
[image]

My hope is that the Virtual Keyboard API will eventually be implemented in the Web Views that Ionic uses to run on Native devices which will enable us to use it in our Mobile Apps!